# Using tortoisesvn for version control: guidance for beginners

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, windows-7-x64

I'm working on a project since last few months. Now I have few more people working on the same project for different modules in it. For this purpose I want to have a central (shared) copy with all which can be accessed by others through LAN connection (we don't have any server).

I went through various links but could not understand any of them completely. I downloaded `tortoisesvn` and installed on my PC.

Now here are my queries:

```
    1) How to create a repository (folder) on my machine where I can put all my code to share with others?
    2) Once a repository (folder) is created, How can I add my source-code to this directory?
(I'm a bit confused about creating directory in Repo-browser, checkout, etc. Which one to use to add my source-code to the repository?
Should I just copy my source-code in repository folder, right click on all of them and do 'add'? Or some other steps are required?)
    3) Once source-code is added in repository, how to share it with other users on LAN?
    4) Is there any other directory required to be created to checkout the code from repo?
```

Consider following details while answering:

I have my source-code in my eclipse-workspace. `E:\eclipse\worspace\MyFirstProject`.

I want to create svn repository in a folder `E:\svn_repo\`. All my future projects will be added in this repository so as to be accessed by others to work on it. Say, `E:\svn_repo\MyFirstProject` will be the repo directory for above mentioned project.

If new folder for checkout is needed, I'd like to create it at: `E:\svn_checkout\MyFirstProject` for above project.

Can anybody give my step-wise guidance for above requirement?

I am working on a 64-bit windows-7 OS.

Comment: Got a tutorial link as desired at [this link](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html) and also at [this tutorial link](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a server, or at least one of the workstations to act as a server. Do not try to directly access the svn filesystem from lots of workstations.

Install [VisualSvn Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) on the workstation that you want to host the central project repository and then make everyone (including the owner of the workstation) access the repo via http. This will not only let you move the project repo to a server if you get one, but will also be significantly safer -you will not get any corruption because 2 people tried to write the same file at the same time, or lost network connection half way through writing. Direct access to the svn repo file is only to be used for servers when reading revisions.

TortoiseSVN is a client tool (like AnkhSVN or VisualSVN's visual studio addin). You'll like VisualSVN Server as its very easy to use and integrates with Windows well.